# Become first responder without animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

Is there a way for a `UITextField` to become first responder without the animation of the keyboard? That is, make it such that the keyboard just appears?

Basically, I'm pushing a second `UIViewController` over the `UIViewController` that has the `UITextField`, and when that second view controller gets popped off the stack, I want the `UITextField` to immediately have first responder status so that when the second view controller gets popped, the user never notices the text field wasn't first responder.

Right now I have it so that when it's popped, the keyboard animates up the screen, but I don't want that to be seen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a UIView animation like so

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

[textField becomeFirstResponder];  // <---- Only edit this line

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will cause the keyboard to suddenly appear.

You can do the same but with `-resignFirstResponder`

Swift ..

```
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.0)
    UIView.setAnimationDelay(0.0)
    someTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    UIView.commitAnimations()
```

Comment: Wait what is UIView? Is that something like `self.view`, or is that the `UITextField`? Also, should I just put this in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: UIView references the class.  The only part you need to change is `textField`. This should be the name of the UITextField you want to make the firstResponder

Comment: Hm I did that, but nothing's changed... I think the thing is that the view controller with the text field is already loaded. When the view is created, it's appearing instantly like it should, but when I pop back to this view controller from another controller on the stack, it's already loaded so this never happens. I put this code in `viewWillAppear`. What should I do?

Comment: I placed the code in both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` separately, and it seems to work for me.  The `viewDidAppear` is a little slow, but it still works. I'm not too sure what problem you're having...

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: what a great tip.   I put in the swift, @DavidSkrundz

Answer (score 1):

Just set it as the first responder in `-viewDidAppear` to make the user never notice the field having lost its status.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self isViewLoaded] && self.textField)
        [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

I've put a short sample project up on [dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54072935/Example.zip) using this code, if you'd like it.

Comment: You forgot to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` - might cause you some issues down the road. Also calling `self.view` to check if it exists on view controller will trigger view creation, it's better to use `[self isViewLoaded]`. Finally, in this particular case the fact that you're within `viewWillAppear` method tells that view was already created

Comment: Nevermind, forgetting my basic iOS.  Also, the self.view check does _not_ force a view creation (tested just now), because -loadView is called when the View Controller's view is nil, which is what I'm checking for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm, mot sure what iOS version do you use or at what point do you call `becomeFirstResponder`
Calling `[textFieldReference becomeFirstResponder]` in `viewWillAppear:` for iOS5/iOS6 seems to work just the way you wanted it to:

it's being called just before view controller will show it's view (that's if you don't handle view controller hierarchy manually) and as soon as it appears in navigation controller keyboard is already presented and text field has focus.

That said, there is no public way that I heard off that would allow to specify keyboard appearance style.

Comment: The public way is UIView's Core Animation wrapper like in @NSArray's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this was an option when the question was first asked, but [`UIView.performWithoutAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622484-performwithoutanimation) works appropriately.

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.composeView.focusTextField()
}
```