# UITextView Keyboard with keyboardAccessoryView turns blue (is inverted) after Springboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview, ios8, xcode6

On a iOS8 device or iOS8 simulator:

I have a UITextView which becomes first responder. Everything is fine until the app resigns active (via home key press).

Upon the app becoming active once more the keyboard's appearance is mutated - see image

[image]

The keyboard does have an keyboardAccessoryView which I have removed from the image for client privacy. However if  remove the keyboardAccessoryView the bad behaviour does not occur.

The only solution I have to date is to resignFirstResponder on **UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification** and becomeFirstResponder on **UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification**.

Has anyone else seen this issue and [hopefully] fixed it?

For completeness here is a screenshot of the keyboard before the app goes to Springboard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best **mitigation** so far is as follows -

Add notification handlers to capture when the app becomes active / reactive

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(activateKeyboard)
                                            name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(deactivateKeyboard)
                                            name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];
```

Then after finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917209/741626) SO answer which is a bit old I tried to make the **becomeFirstResponder** happen as quickly as possible.

```
- (void)activateKeyboard;
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0f
               animations:^{
                 [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
               }];
}

- (void)deactivateKeyboard;
{
  [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```